# Segregating values with numbers in a list of strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

```
dataframe_name[new_column_name] = int(any(char.isdigit() for char in dataframe_name[existing_column_name])
```

or

```
for i in range(0, len(data_frame))):
    dataframe_name[new_column_name][i] = int(any(char.isdigit() for char in dataframe_name[existing_column_name][i]))
```

Please help me understand the difference between the above two codes. While the former gives a wrong result (it's giving only *False* and no *True* values in the new column), the latter works for me but only partially. It is not converting *True* & *False* into *1* & *0* respectively despite using int().

Comment: @AMC I need to form a new column which gives '1' for strings with digits in them and '0' for strings without digits.

Comment: My question was why use 0/1 instead of actual boolean values?

Comment: Because I have a task which demands only that!

Comment: What is `intany` in that first code snippet?

Comment: It is int(any..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to return 0 for condition and 1 for another, you can do this

```py
def int_condition(existing_column_name, i):
  return 1 if any(char.isdigit() for char in dataframe_name[existing_column_name][i]) else 0
```

Comment: Are you sure *[i]* would be there after existing_column_name?

Comment: add it as function param as well

Comment: Here len(dataframe_name) = 10000.

Comment: Why are we adding 'i'?

Comment: I need to form the entire column with length 10000.

Comment: The code you suggested is giving all '0's and no '1's.

Comment: this means that this `any(char.isdigit() for char in dataframe_name[existing_column_name][i]) ` that I copied from your code is always true

Comment: So when we run the function, what value should we give for the i param?

Comment: And it is not actually always true. Some contain digits, while some don't.